# Data Formatters temporarily unavailable

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Im trying to use Date Formatters (NSDateFormatter), but I keep getting this error:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")
```

Comment: Yes I did. It seems that I am missing some files (for some unknown reason). So I am updating to the latest Beta 6 (I was on Beta 5). Hopefully that fixes it up a little.

Comment: Upgrading to Beta 6 didn't help...what could the problem be?

Comment: What beta? Even SDK 3.2 is out of beta already.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is nothing to do with NSDateFormatter - the message pasted in saying "Data Formatters" is correct.  You will get this message in several situations, possibly most commonly when unable to find a linked in shared library at launch time.  You may also get it when short of memory while running, in which case start looking for leaks.

(not enough rep to comment).

Comment: turns out i was calling a date too early. all fixed now

Comment: This is correct. Anyone coming to this thread should IMO disregard the other answers (except Mary Kay's, which might be helpful). The problem has nothing to do with Xcode version etc.

Comment: I think this guy point the solution for this problem too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843903/data-formatters-temporarily-unavailable-will-re-try-after-a-continue

Comment: also, this error is shown when dynamic linker can't find symbols for a library being loaded

Answer (score 2):

I've had the "Data Formatters temporarily unavailable..." problem when I put a breakpoint in an unusual position (such as on the exception handler). In the Debugger window, click on "Show Breakpoints" and see if you have something you forgot about -- I did.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, building the code on 3.2 as target solved the problem. Maybe this can give a hint, as i am not happy with this solution.

Comment: Even I think that might be due to upgrading the system to new OS & also with Beta Version.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the same problem. Mine had to do with stack overflow (no pun intended ;-) since I was overriding a setter and calling the same setter from within, forming an endless recursion. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was the cause:

```
NSLog(@"%@", url);
```

where url is a NSURL, not NSString.

This wasn't a problem in the simulator, but it generated the "Data Formatters temporarily unavailable" on the device.