# Program received signal: “0”. Data Formatters temporarily unavailable

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I'm working on an iPad app that downloads a CSV file from the web and parses the file into a NSMutableArray. (I'm using the code from http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxvi-parsing-csv-data suggested in another post).

When I run in the simulator, everything works perfectly, but when I run on the device, I get the following error:

```
Program received signal:  “0”.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")
(gdb)
```

Does anyone know why this would pop up?  Google isn't helping me here... :(

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data Formatters temporarily unavailable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573477/data-formatters-temporarily-unavailable)

Comment: The signal 0, not EXC_BAD_ACCESS, and there are no Date formatters being used in the code (the other poster's problem was with a date formatter).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Signal 0 usually (but not always) points to your app being killed for using too much memory.

Your view controllers should received the memory warning method in a low memory situation, and it is up to you to free up some memory when they arrive. If you don't free any memory and continue to use more memory the app will be forcibly quit.

The data formatters message in the console relates to the debugger. For some reason the debugger was unable to load the data formatters used to represent the data in the application. probably because the phone didn't have any memory left for them.

Comment: Please check this question -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224103/data-formatters-temporarily-unavailable-error/8225218#8225218