# App crashes due to lot of images

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Am creating an interactive book. in that am using lots of animation. i used sprite sheet.Sometimes  my app crashes while loading one scene to another scene.

Comment: post some code. in which method is your app crashing?

Comment: Program received signal:  “0”.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered: [Program received signal: “0”. Data Formatters temporarily unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813454/program-received-signal-0-data-formatters-temporarily-unavailable)

Short answer: Use less frames. That is your overall solution.