# How to load High Quality .gif image in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, animated-gif

By extracting .gif image,i got 48 frames with resolution of (1024*768). And i Stored those frames in a Array like this.

```
NSMutableArray *splashImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=1;i <= 48;i ++)
    {
        [splashImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"img%d.jpg",i]]];
    }
    [ImageView setAnimationImages:splashImages];
    [ImageView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [ImageView startAnimating];
```

And i gave this to UIImageView with duration of 1s,By running application,it went out like smoothless animating and even it getting stuck.

Any Solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Before all, I am afraid that may cause memory warning if you load all 48 images in to memory, check it with Instrument.

================================

You probably need to force it do the decompressing and rendering before, check this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116194/any-way-to-encode-a-png-faster-than-uiimagepngrepresentation) and this [link2](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/10/avoiding-image-decompression-sickness/)

Try this, it causes the image to decompress, even though the image context is just 1 pixel large.:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1, 1));
    [decompressedImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

or something like this:

```
CGDataProviderRef imageDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)imageData);
    CGImageRef image = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(imageDataProvider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image), CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image), 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmapContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);

    CGDataProviderRelease(imageDataProvider);
    CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);

    if (image){
        decompressedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
        CGImageRelease(image);
    }
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your idea.but,decompression cause's image to loose it's quality.

Answer (score 0):

You approach is not going to work. See [how-to-resolve-memory-crash-in-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610651/how-to-resolve-memory-crash-in-iphone/7659604#comment24955968_7659604) and [loading-images-for-animation-in-uiimageview-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617910/loading-images-for-animation-in-uiimageview-ios/17225223#17225223) for some examples of problems you will run into. You would be better off just encoding a movie in h.264 and playing it with AVPlayer. That is a far better approach than creating a bunch of full screen .gif files.