# Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'

Tags: iphone, ios-4.2

I am new in iPhone technology. I am run my application on device, but I get this error :-

> Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")

on console.

So please provide me proper solution of this error. or how to solve the memory problem in iPhone.

Comment: I would reinstall XCode to be honest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data Formatters temporarily unavailable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573477/data-formatters-temporarily-unavailable)

Comment: i have reinstall the xcode in mac but i get same problem when i run the application in iphone

Comment: Hey did you updated your system to new OS ? Even I faced the same issue after installing Xcode4 & between that uprgrading to beta version.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly this error is due to memory leaks or due to the leaks of the autorelease pools inside your application make sure that you are releasing them properly.

if you want a more detailed error message then in that case i would say that connect your device and select window->organiser->select your device name-> and check the device log or console tab for any errors.

Also remember the [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) are your best friend when it comes to memory related issues