# Library error in my iPad application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am getting the following error:

> Program received signal:  “0”.
>       Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

It's due to short memory while running, in this case please look for leaks.
The Message pasted in saying "Data Formatters" will get in several situations, possibly most commonly when unable to find a linked in shared library at launch time.

Please check this link too, similiar question,
[Data Formatters temporarily unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573477/data-formatters-temporarily-unavailable)